# Gmail app always says "no connection"

Tags: gmail, connection-issues

even though I have a connection and can browse or do other things with connections. This happens when connected to both 3G and WiFi. Did anyone have the same problem, or know how to solve this?

the phone is galaxy s with os 2.1

Comment: Does it ever happen when you're connected ONLY with wifi or ONLY with 3G?

Comment: yes. I mean it happens both when I am connected with wiFi and when I am connected with 3G. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of the [steps to kick-start a truculent app](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it/158#158)?

Have you re-entered your account and password information?

Have you tried changing any of the sync options for your Google account?

Comment: Gmail does not show up in Settings | Applications | Manage applications :(

Comment: You must still be using the built-in app. There's an update available in the Market. You should install that.

Comment: I couldn't find a Gmail app in the market

Comment: @Louis, Try using AppBrain to start the Android Market installer: http://www.appbrain.com/app/gmail/com.google.android.gm

Comment: when i click the install from market link, the market says that the app is not found.

Comment: ah I see it's for 2.2 and higher. Mine is 2.1